# DirectX poor Sprite Performance

Tags: c++, 2d, animation, sprites, directx9

I render an animation with 100+ frames. (Direct X9,Sprites / Pngs)
I load them all in an array and render them.

How i do it:
Load all frames in an array of bytes.
When i need the frame x, i create the sprite from the specific buffer with "D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemoryEx & D3DXCreateSprite".
I do that, bec loading them at the start& at device lost etc takes ages.

My question now: What can i do? Creating the sprite takes very long but why? I googled that including all frames into 1 png and rendering regions from it is faster but isnt that like crazy ? I would  get files sizes of 100k x 1080px.

The scenario looks the following:
- Consumes about 100 mb ram (i am okay with that bec its only displaying 1 animation, so about 100 mb total ram for the program)
- Consumes a lot of cpu (not okay, its just rendering 1 sprite at a frame, why does it have way more consume than my 3d rendering)

Comment: Why are you using the [legacy DirectX 9 API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and the [deprecated D3DX9 utility library](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/) (where ``ID3DXSprite`` comes from)? Why not use DirectX 11?

Answer (score 3):

Sprites in Direct3D are just textured triangles (or rather two triangles forming a quadrilateral). As such, the performance hit is because each time you *change* the source texture it has to flush the sprite batch and submit it as a `Draw`. The key to Direct3D performance is to get as much work into each `Draw` as possible. You are basically drawing two triangles per `Draw` which is always going to perform slowly. If you were drawing the same texture a few thousand times in a row, it would take about the same time as drawing a single sprite.

The general solution to this kind of issue is to use a texture atlas (or specifically for sprites, a 'sprite sheet') where you pack the individual sprites into the same texture. The main challenge is that you are limited to the hardware support for maximum texture sizes. With Direct3D 9 Shader Model 3 hardware, the best you can do is 4096 x 4096. With Direct3D 11, it depends on your target [Direct3D hardware feature level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876.aspx) but it can range from 4096 x 4096 up to 16384 x 16384. With Direct3D 11 and Feature Level 10.0 or better, you can even get tricky and pack sprites into a 8192 x 8192 textures in an 2D texture array of up to 512.

I have an example [Sprite Sheet implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SpriteSheet) using [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started)'s `SpriteBatch` class.